# Image based off of Combobox choice

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, jcombobox

I have a combobox with a list of automakers. When the user selects and automaker I was it to display their logo. I have a JLabel set up that I was going to put the logo into

Comment: Show the code. How do you manage the pics? Is it a List, or an array, or is the logo maybe a field of the object in the combobx? There´s no way to tell you how to do it, if you don´t show us what you ´ve got.

Comment: A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help you get better help sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have ImageIcon array with the same indexes you have in you combobox

You should add listener to combobox where you should add method doing this

```
ImageIcon [] icons;
myJCombobox.addItemListener(new ItemListner()){
     public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
          myJLabel.setIcon(icons[myJCombobox.getSelectedIndex()]);
     }
});
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ItemListener` :

```
JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
box.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
            label.setIcon(icon);
        }

    }
});
```

Read about writing an [`ItemListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) and using [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the JComboBox API. If you read the API you will find a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Combo Boxes`, which has a working example that does exactly what you want.

Start by reading the API and the tutorials BEFORE posting a question on the forum.

Comment: @GarrettShaw, `Did you ever think that maybe the tutorial didn't help` - Not in this case. The tutorial does exactly what you want. Where is your `SSCCE` that shows what you have attempted? Where did you state you read the tutorial? Where did you ask question about code in the tutorial you didn't understand?. Our assumption is that you haven't used the tutorial as a resource. The forum is here to teach you how to do basic problem solving. The better your question, the better the answer that will be given. Everything in this answer/comment is useful if you are truly willing to learn.